# Send message over the lan on Windows-7

Tags: windows-7, net

What'is the alternate command for "net send" on computer running windows-7?
I've try "msg", but this command, seems cannot send message to one computer over the lan.

Thank you
Luciano

Answer (score 2):

The "Messenger Service", which back-ended the old `NET SEND` functionality is not "supported" in Windows versions newer than Vista. In these newer versions of Windows, a Terminal Services API ([WTSSendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383842(VS.85).aspx)) is used to send messages to sessions. That's what the `msg` utility is calling, ultimately.

Setting the REG_DWORD value "AllowRemoteRPC" at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" to 1 will permit a machine to receive remote RPC calls to Terminal Services APIs. That will permit the `msg` utility to work on remote Windows 7 machines, so long as the user who is invoking the `msg` command is an Administrator on the remote machine.

I agree w/ Warner insofar as this is probably a poor way to do instant messaging. An email or dedicated IM system would probably be a better choice in terms of cross-platform compatibilty and future OS's.

Comment: Thank you for the correction.  Feel free to take my recommendation for your answer.

Comment: @Warner: Fair enough. I'll expect you to catch me when I make an incorect Linux-related statement (since I'm at an "I can hold my own" level of skill when it comes to that platform). >smile<